# Show UINavigationController with UIViewController animation

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, ios-animations

I have a storyboard with few `UINavigationControllers` and `UIViewControllers`.

[image: Main.storyboard]

When I `performSegueWithIdentifier(..)` from the second to third window default animation is right to left slide. But when I `performSegueWithIdentifier(..)` from the third window to `UINavigationController` the animation is from bottom to top slide. How to set `UIViewController` -> `UINavigationController` animation to one like `UIViewController` -> `UIViewController`?

Comment: if you need present viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
YOURVC *vc = [[YOURVC alloc]init];
UINavigationController *VCNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
```

And when you are calling from 1 to 3 or any call

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

or from 2 to 1 also you can call like this and instead you can call

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or to root view controller use

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or to a particular vc

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:yourvc Animated:YES];
```

Then if you want to show navigation keep it, or if you want to hide you can hide it.

Comment: I know how to navigate between controllers, but will it fix the animation issue?

Comment: yes by navigation it will animate to left , when you use presentViewController method it will come from bottom to top.